# Векторная графика для 3D проекта в unity

Tags: unity3d, svg, 3d, 2d

Вопрос:

Вектор для юнити только под 2D пригоден? 
Или можно как то его для 3D модели использовать?

Comment: 2D картинка - 3д модель, как правило, состоящая из 2х полигонов, так что проблем в отрисовке нет. Лучше укажите, какую конечную цель вы преследуете. UI?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker хочу попробовать сделать мини уровень для игры (ради теста, понравится или нет) . Уровень будет в 3D. Есть персонаж, площадка и пара элементов для взаимодействия. Что бы отрисовать все это, вектор никак не использовать? Для интерфейса я вроде понял, что можно применять вектор,  а для самих объектов игры?

Comment: Так я же наоборот сказал, что вектор будет использовать полигоны в любом случае, а значит его можно использовать в 3д :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker спасибо, понял :)

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос задан просто критически странно. И подозреваю что автор сам до конца не понимает что он хочет сам.

Но предполагаю что в вопросе имелись ввиду NURBS поверхности. **Они из коробки в юнити не поддерживаются.** Но в теории.... есть ассеты и их можно поискать. На практике не уверен кто-то этим занимался или нет, так что ванговать не буду.

Наглядная информация о разнице между Mash и NURBS:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lm1G5jJ6JC8

Но и они не совсем векторная графика в том смысле, в котором она представляется автору. Там есть некоторые ограничения, на сколько я знаю... Хотя я могу и ошибатся.